# Typescript: Generics, infer the value of object if key is given

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, type-inference

Let's say we have some kind of dispatch functions that tries to update a certain prop on an object.
Is it possible to have proper type inference in the following scenario?

```js
type EntityA = {
  name: string;
  id: number
}

type EntityB = {
  id: number;
  test1: number;
  test2: string;
  test3: number;
  test4: string;
}

type EntityAction<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?:
  | {
    type: 'UPDATE_ENTITY';
    payload: T;
  } |
  {
    type: 'UPDATE_PROP';
    propName: K;
    payload: T[K];
  };
}[keyof T];

function dispatch<T>(action: EntityAction<T>) {
  // omitted logic because it's not relevant
  console.log(action);
}

dispatch<EntityA>({
  type: 'UPDATE_PROP',
  propName: 'name',
});

dispatch<EntityB>({
  type: 'UPDATE_PROP',
  propName: 'test4',
  payload: ''
})
```

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.0-dev.20230205#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsAlqAglAvFA3gWAFBRRwCGAthAFxECupARhAE4Dc+hiAJlQM7COJwA5vgC++fKEiwEyEACEM2NlE5U4tBi2XAIvAIxqNTVgSg7eAJh58Bgk4XPAAzIfrHtu4ABZr-ISbE8fAgADzAAe0ZgM3BoeCRUAGMkcLgAHgAVAD5FXFMAbQBpFTgoAGsIEHCAMygMgF0AWgB+CmUAHyVTB1iqAHIAVQAFABEUDJgAfRgAOQyASQyATT77QigwYhAAG3DiLjq1kSh25Tz1mMh+4bGJyaGAJQB5IdXlQjBGcLAZskooQprD5bXb7KgZIr1I4BfIVKq1BomfDVahwZKIVJQDiIbibYCJAAWmSyAApiOjUlR4rIUBT0tkAJRdQiJVLccLbCAAOl2gjJdIZAXEeGxuOI+KJ1NQpPOl3+g1G4ymjxefQANMpPt9fuR+iRyOrRILhaK8YS0lL5DLtL0oArbsrnq8NaYtT8-v1HF5Da6QXsDn0+kagA)

I managed to infer the types based on a reply found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72244908/8210103) (Thanks @jcalz) but as soon as I have more than 1 prop in a type it doesn't work correctly.

Given EntityA, if i dispatch the following:

```
dispatch<EntityA>({ type: 'UPDATE_PROP',propName: 'id' })
```

it correctly lets me know that the prop `payload` is missing
However, if I pass

```
dispatch<EntityA>({ type: 'UPDATE_PROP',propName: 'name' })
```

It tells me that
`Type '"name"' is not assignable to type '"id"'.` (or whatever the last prop in the type is).

Any idea if this can be "fixed" to properly infer the type of `payload`? Is it even possible in this setup?
It seems to work if EntityAction as:

```
export type EntityAction<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?:
  {
    type: 'UPDATE_PROP';
    propName: K;
    payload: T[K];
  };
}[keyof T];
```

Comment: I think it works fine as is. The error message is misleading. If you add the `payload` property to your first example, the error goes away.

Comment: Yeah I agree, I was wondering if there's a way to "unconfuse" typescript.

Comment: It would probably worth it to open an issue on Github to get this fixed.

Comment: This looks like [ms/TS#46374](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46374), a known bug.  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeah seems to be the same issue. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a known bug, reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#46374](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46374), in which an "incomplete" value assigned to a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) yields a compiler error which complains about the wrong property.

It looks like it was introduced in TypeScript 3.9, sometime between [`typescript@3.9.0-dev.20200328`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript/v/3.9.0-dev.20200328) and [`typescript@3.9.0-dev.20200407`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript/v/3.9.0-dev.20200407), which leads me to believe that it was probably caused by the work done in [microsoft/TypeScript#37589](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/37589), "Disallow partial matches for discriminant properties when generating error messages", which changed the way discriminated union error messages were generated, fixing a different bug but apparently causing this one.

Anyway, the bug is currently scheduled to be fixed for TypeScript 5.1, but it has been rescheduled several times already, so it's not clear if this will actually happen.